# Incorrect shorthand if else statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following ternary operator:

```
<?php (strcmp($activetab,'profile') == 0 ? echo "active" : '');  ?>
```

Unfortunately it is not working as expected. I wish that if the condition was true that `active` would be echoed, otherwise nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just miss <?= (... ? .. : ..) ?> to echo your ternary result.

Answer (score 5):

Try now

```
<?php echo (strcmp($activetab,'profile') == 0) ?  "active" : '';  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$comp ? $a : $b` syntax is **not** really shorthand for just

`if ( $comp ) { $a; } else { $b }`

It is actually kind of:

`function ($comp, $a, $b) { if ( $comp ) { return $a; } else { return $b; } }`

So indeed try `echo (strcmp($activetab,'profile') == 0 ? "active" : '');`

Comment: Took the freedom to revert the [somewhat destructive edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1947771); no idea why the others approved it.

Comment: @ClassStacker - They see someone with a gold badge and assume it's a valid edit. Some people need to learn to read more ...

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your code like this:

```
<?php echo (strcmp($activetab,'profile') == 0 ?  "active" : '');  ?>
```